# method or function "sanitize" has already been declared error on line 2

Tags: php

I have error on line 2 says function has been declared. This is for a login\registration system. Site is now unresponsive with all blank pages.

```
         <?php
function array sanitize(&$item) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}


function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}


function output_errors($errors) {
    return '<ul><li>' .implode('</li><li>', $output) . '</li></ul>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Start using prepared/parameterized queries (in PDO or Mysqli) and you could delete those functions.

Comment: `function array sanitize` is not a valid syntax

Comment: what could i use instead of this ?

Comment: @fusion3k - `array_sanitize`? You just can't have a space in the function name like you have.

Comment: Might I ask why you're referencing `&$item` into the function? And both those *sanitize* function seem rather redundant. Why not simply call `mysql_real_escape_string()` directly, if all those functions are doing is returning `mysql_real_escape_string()` anyway?

Comment: thanks got it working now

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration you have here:

```
function array sanitize(&$item) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}
```

is not a valid function declaration in PHP.

```
function arraySanitize(&$item) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}
```

Is probably what you are looking for.